# How to create a Dictionary of different types of Encodable values

Tags: swift

I have a simple function

```
getResource<T: Encodable>(_ params: [String: T])
```

where it takes a dictionary of `String` and generic `T` values that conform to `Encodable`. That's great. I can do this:

```
getResource(["number": 1, "otherNumber": 2])
```

However, this fails when I try to do

```
getResource(["number": 1, "otherLocation": Location.zero])
```

where `Location` is a struct that conforms to `Encodable`:

```
struct Location: Codable {
    static let zero = Location(latitude: 0, longitude: 0)
    
    let latitude: Double
    let longitude: Double
}
```

Basically, i want to mix and match the types in my `params`, where the params are all conforming to `Encodable`. Is that possible?

Comment: @matt yea, i see that. that's why i asked, if there's a way for me to declare the type so that it can take any type of Encodable. Not sure if my question makes sense? or maybe i am not clear in what i am trying to ask.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to accomplish but you can try `func getResource(_ params: [String: any Encodable]) {`

Comment: What you are probably looking for is called existencial any. Take a look at [Introduce existential any](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0335-existential-any.md) or https://www.hackingwithswift.com/swift/5.6/existential-any

Comment: @LeoDabus yea thats what i was looking for, just didn't know what it was called. thx